# Setting default value of dropdownlist in C#

Tags: c#, html, razor

I currently have a dropdownlist that looks like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("ItemID", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })
```

which produces a default value of "-- Select --"

But I want to change this so the default is the current ItemID in the model.

So something like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("ItemID", null, @Model.ItemID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument, the one you've set null, should be a collection of SelectListItem objects, one of which has its Selected property set to true. In your code:

```
 model.ItemID = 123;

 model.Items = dbquery.Items.Select(dbitem => new SelectListItem(){ 
    Text = dbitem.DisplayName,
    Value = dbitem.ID,
    Selected = (model.ItemID == dbitem.ID)
 });
```

Then in your markup:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ItemID", @Model.Items, @Model.ItemID, htmlAttribu...
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument here should be entire list of values.
i.e.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ItemID", Model.ListOfValues, Model.ItemID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })
```

such that Model.ItemID should exist in Model.ListOfValues list